# Android app performance

Tags: android, performance-testing, performance

Is there any graph or mechanism  to test the performance of an android app? I am making an Android application for client server communication and using Rest and different methods.

How can I measure its performance in terms of processing and battery life?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you use the built in profiling tools.  Here is a tutorial:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html

Comment: Very Interesting and and any suggestions about battery performance for a particular app

Comment: Honestly, I haven't looked into it much. From what I've deduced over building and maintaining a few apps is that, in general, battery usage developers can control is directly related to the number of simultaneous threads you run, up to about 8. Then its just flat unless you're doing a bunch of extended GPS/Bluetooth/NFC stuff. I looked under the emulators 'spare parts' menu and there is a Battery history app, but it force closes on me, so, might be something to investigate.